# MVC best practice for displaying static generated data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Question background:**

I have a two page MVC 4 web app. The first page's view currently has its data manually typed into the View as its static i.e nothing is being passed to the View from its associated Controller method, as shown:

Index controller method:

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml View:

```
<div class="titleHeader">Welcome To This Test Example</div>
```

**Best practice:**

Is the above example OK to use, or should I generate a ViewModel object on the Index controller, populate the static data then return it to the View? As Shown:

Index Controller Index method with ViewModel:

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
  HomePageVM homepageVM = new HomePageVM
  {
    WelcomeMessage = "Welcome To This Test Example";
  };

  return View(homepageVM);
}
```

Index.cshtml now bound to the HomePageVM ViewModel:

```
@model TestPage.Models.HomePageVM

<div class="titleHeader">@Model.WelcomeMessage</div>
```

Comment: It's up to you. If you only need static data, your first version is correct. The second version will be helpfull if in the future you need to add dynamic content to your view.

Comment: This question is possibly better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the principle of **not** [gold plating](http://blog.codinghorror.com/gold-plating/) your code.

You don't need the view model (right now) so don't add it. If you want a view model later then it's simple to add one. Your goal should be to **create the simplest solution possible**. For me that means the view model (or any other solution that's not pure HTML) only add's unnecessary complexity.

---

The answer from stefan about resources again seems gold plating to me. It's based on the:

> will be able to easily port to a multi language website.

Is your site multi language? Is it ever likely to be? If **no**, this is gold-plating.

Comment: Nice article and I agree, but there's a key point in: `Is it ever likely to be?`. Usually this is up to business requirements but nevertheless chief-engineering might conclude that extra requirements must be in place. Otherwise why keep code open for extension and closed for change? What I want to say, we must be critical, from both point of views :)

Comment: Yes @Stefan , it is dependant on requirements and time pressures. If you gold plate and it happens that what you added was useful, then you're up. But you should ask yourself, is what I'm adding here likely to be ever used? Is there any benefit to adding this functionality now? Does it make it quicker later or if it's just going to take the same amount of time to add it later, why not add that functionality when (and if) it's needed. If you add code(complexity) and it's never used, you've wasted your time/money **and** made it harder to maintain in the future for no benefit

Answer (score 5):

I think (opinion), it's best to use `Resource` files for static data.

With these Resource file you will be able to easily port to a multi language website.

Basically you'll need to create `resx` files, make the entries public.

In your cshtml you can access it by:

```
<div class="titleHeader">@Resources.WelcomeMessage</div>
```

Depending on the UIThread's culture info it is able to select the appropriate language.

You can find a tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati

As for your options:

1) There is really no need to create a ViewModel for static data unless you'll expect it to be dynamic in the future (although it's bad habit to develop now for future requirements).

2) Hard coded strings in the cshtml, it possible, but not suited for multi-language. There is 1 benefit I would like to mention: it's easier for non-developers to alter the html.

Comment: How do you know the OP needs to make a multi language site? This if there is no multi language requirement this is [gold plating](http://blog.codinghorror.com/gold-plating/)

Comment: @Liam: OP's question title states `best practices`; so I gave multiple options, as I think OP will benefit from.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really a code guru but:
Why use viewbag or even viewmodel when you just want to show one line of static text? You don't usually use calculator when you want to add 2 + 2 don't you ?

`<div>` seems fine to me in this one

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very true, but as this is an MVC app normally there is a 'Model' involved and not just a Controller and View. I could also implement a ViewModel that may (later on) be populated by a database so the logic would be there ready to go. Currently though I'm going to stick with what I have.

Comment: Viewmodel is very good thing if your project is:   1) big enough  2) has Db and models or at least collections and classes 3) you would like to display some of them in your views